# On successful payment, redirect to a page with Paypal

Tags: paypal

I have a really simplistic website selling game servers. I have a pay with Paypal option with a non-hosted Paypal button that looks like:

```html
<form name="_xclick<?=$type?>" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick<?=$type?>">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@site.com">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://example.com/success.php?items=<?=$items?>&user=<?=$user?>">
<input type="hidden" id= "price" name="amount" value="<?=$price?>">
<input type="image" src="paypal.gif" border="0" name="submit">
</form>
```

As soon as the user is done paying, I need them to be redirected to success.php with the GET parameters as shown in the "return" hidden input. However, they are only brought back to my website if they click a small button on the paypal website "Return to seller", but without being redirected, their order will never be processed.

I read up on Paypal's site and it looks like the only option is to set up PayPal Express Checkout and create a completely new button and integrate my site with their API's.

That is way more than I want to do to just get a redirect after a payment. Is this the only way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are processing orders is flawed, assuming that the success.php page does some sort of logic (send an invoice email/update inventory) you need to move this to into a script that processes Paypal's IPN (https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/)

IPN will send a message to your server for Paypal transactions, that one way you can 100% accurately process orders (or like you said express checkout).

Why? You cannot 100% rely on a customer to return to your page after paying.